# He ripped out a fathom and a half o' brimstone Spanish This is from the note of Kipling Society

Tags: meaning

> '"You told me to bring cannon-shot next time, an' I've brought 'em."
>
> 'He saw we had. **He ripped out a fathom and a half o' brimstone
>   Spanish**, and he swung down on our rail, and he kissed me before all
>   his fine young captains. His men was swarming out of the lower ports
>   ready to unload us. When he saw how I'd considered all his likely
>   wants, he kissed me again.

This is from ["Simple Simon" in "Rewards and Fairies" by Kipling.](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=vxsvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT5999&lpg=PT5999&dq=scrapin%27%20his%20hold%20for%20a%20few%20last%20rounds%20shot&source=bl&ots=o1SMVM17p5&sig=EZvvZVxYWkcFnmdOzLx6bTtfEj8&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl3u64_qjYAhVFW7wKHYK1DaMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=scrapin'%20his%20hold%20for%20a%20few%20last%20rounds%20shot&f=false)

I do not understand the meaning of this.

He ripped out a fathom and a half o' brimstone Spanish

This is from the note of Kipling Society.
[Page 300, line 4] brimstone Spanish Brimstone is sulphur. In this context, 'fiery', or 'burning'. The reader can assume that Drake was swearing exuberantly in Spanish.

I am so glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  The notes on this suggest Kipling 
 is using a very colorful metaphor to say that Drake is swearing, in a fiery and excited way, in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings for **"Ripped out"** is *"burst out with a violent or profane utterance"* (quoting after https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rip+out).

**"A fathom and a half"** is an unit of measurement (equivalent to about 2.7 meters), in this case meaning something like "a lot".

The word **"brimstone"** modifies "Spanish". Brimstone is the alternative name for sulfur, an element associated with fire and heat. Thus, **"brimstone Spanish"** can be understood as "fiery (= aggressive, passionate) Spanish".

In total, the whole sentence is a colorful metaphor which can be interpreted as "he said a lot of violent, passionate things in Spanish," or -- as the note from Kipling Society remarks -- Drake started "swearing exuberantly in Spanish".

Answer (score 0):

**"He ripped out a fathom and a half o' brimstone Spanish"**

'**ripped out**'
is an **idiom** meaning to **tear something out of** something else.

'**a fathom and a half**'
is **a way of measurement**. 1 fathom ~ 1.82 meters.

**o'** is short form for *'of'*, you may have already known that.

I am not sure about **brimstone Spanish**, its blank meaning is **azufre** or  **sulfur** which is a substance. It could be something else.

So, this sentence can be translated into

> "**He torn out a piece of azufre which is about 2.7 meters long and he swung down on our rail**"

This is just my personal opinion but i hope it helps :)

Comment: The note says "The reader can assume that Drake was swearing exuberantly in Spanish." Why do you think this means "he ripped out 2 meters of azufre"? Ripped it out of where?